# Angled Gradient Layer

Tags: swift, uiview, swift2, gradient, cagradientlayer

I have custom `UIView` class that renders a gradient in Swift 2. I'm struggling with making an angled gradient so that it draws from the top-left to the bottom-right. Can somebody help me a bit?

```
import UIKit

class GradientView: UIView {

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        // 1
        self.backgroundColor = ColorPalette.White

        // 2
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds

        // 3
        let color1 = ColorPalette.GrdTop.CGColor as CGColorRef
        let color2 = ColorPalette.GrdBottom.CGColor as CGColorRef
        gradientLayer.colors = [color1, color2]

        // 4
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]

        // 5
        self.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }

}
```

I suspect this should be something else but whatever I input nothing changes.

```
gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
```

Comment: Have you ascertained that your awakeFromNib() is indeed firing?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You don't want to use `locations` to specify the direction of the gradient. Instead use `startPoint` and `endPoint` for that.

The `locations` array is used when one wants to specify where, in between `startPoint` and `endPoint`, the gradient should to take place. For example, if you want the colors to only take place in the middle 10% of the range from the start and end points, you'd use:

```
locations = [0.45, 0.55]
```

The `locations` array doesn't dictate the direction. The `startPoint` and `endPoint` do. So, for a diagonal gradient from upper left to lower right, you would set `startPoint` of `CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)` and an `endPoint` to `CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)`.

For example:

```
@IBDesignable
class GradientView: UIView {

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass { return CAGradientLayer.self }

    private var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer { return layer as! CAGradientLayer }

    @IBInspectable var color1: UIColor = .white { didSet { updateColors() } }
    @IBInspectable var color2: UIColor = .blue  { didSet { updateColors() } }

    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configureGradient()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configureGradient()
    }

    private func configureGradient() {
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
        updateColors()
    }

    private func updateColors() {
        gradientLayer.colors = [color1.cgColor, color2.cgColor]
    }

}
```

E.g.

[image]

Note, unrelated to the immediate issue:

- If you’re going to add the gradient as a sublayer, you want to update this sublayer’s `frame` in `layoutSubviews` so that as the view's `bounds` changes, so does the `frame` of the `gradientLayer`. But, better than that, override the `layerClass` of the view, and it will not only instantiate the `CAGradientLayer` for you, but you also enjoy dynamic adjustments of the gradient as the view’s size changes, notably handling animated changes more gracefully.
- Likewise, I set `color1` and `color2` such that they'll trigger an updating of the gradient, so that any changes in colors will be immediately reflected in the view.
- I made this `@IBDesignable`, so that if I drop this in its own framework, and then add the `GradientView` in IB, I'll see the effect rendered in IB.

For Swift 2 implementation, see [previous revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37039106/7).

Answer (score 27):

## Gradient Start & End Points for Any Angle

### Swift 4.2, Xcode 10.0

Given any angle, my code will set the respective start point and end point of a gradient layer.

If an angle greater than *360°* is inputted, it will use the remainder when divided by *360*.

- An input of *415°* would yield the same result as an input of *55°*

If an angle less than *0°* is inputted, it will reverse the clockwise direction of rotation

- An input of *-15°* would yield the same result as an input of *345°*

---

### Code:

```
public extension CAGradientLayer {

    /// Sets the start and end points on a gradient layer for a given angle.
    ///
    /// - Important:
    /// *0°* is a horizontal gradient from left to right.
    ///
    /// With a positive input, the rotational direction is clockwise.
    ///
    ///    * An input of *400°* will have the same output as an input of *40°*
    ///
    /// With a negative input, the rotational direction is clockwise.
    ///
    ///    * An input of *-15°* will have the same output as *345°*
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - angle: The angle of the gradient.
    ///                  
    public func calculatePoints(for angle: CGFloat) {


        var ang = (-angle).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 360)

        if ang < 0 { ang = 360 + ang }

        let n: CGFloat = 0.5

        switch ang {

        case 0...45, 315...360:
            let a = CGPoint(x: 0, y: n * tanx(ang) + n)
            let b = CGPoint(x: 1, y: n * tanx(-ang) + n)
            startPoint = a
            endPoint = b

        case 45...135:
            let a = CGPoint(x: n * tanx(ang - 90) + n, y: 1)
            let b = CGPoint(x: n * tanx(-ang - 90) + n, y: 0)
            startPoint = a
            endPoint = b

        case 135...225:
            let a = CGPoint(x: 1, y: n * tanx(-ang) + n)
            let b = CGPoint(x: 0, y: n * tanx(ang) + n)
           startPoint = a
            endPoint = b

        case 225...315:
            let a = CGPoint(x: n * tanx(-ang - 90) + n, y: 0)
            let b = CGPoint(x: n * tanx(ang - 90) + n, y: 1)
            startPoint = a
            endPoint = b

        default:
            let a = CGPoint(x: 0, y: n)
            let b = CGPoint(x: 1, y: n)
            startPoint = a
            endPoint = b

        }
    }

    /// Private function to aid with the math when calculating the gradient angle
    private func tanx(_ : CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return tan( * CGFloat.pi / 180)
    }


    // Overloads

    /// Sets the start and end points on a gradient layer for a given angle.
    public func calculatePoints(for angle: Int) {
        calculatePoints(for: CGFloat(angle))
    }

    /// Sets the start and end points on a gradient layer for a given angle.
    public func calculatePoints(for angle: Float) {
        calculatePoints(for: CGFloat(angle))
    }

    /// Sets the start and end points on a gradient layer for a given angle.
    public func calculatePoints(for angle: Double) {
        calculatePoints(for: CGFloat(angle))
    }

}
```

---

### Usage:

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

// Setup gradient layer...

// Gradient Direction: →
gradient.calculatePoints(for: 0)

// Gradient Direction: ↗︎
gradient.calculatePoints(for: -45)

// Gradient Direction: ←
gradient.calculatePoints(for: 180)

// Gradient Direction: ↓
gradient.calculatePoints(for: 450)
```

---

## Mathematical Explanation

So I actually just recently spent a lot of time trying to answer this myself. Here are some example angles just to help understand and visualize the clockwise direction of rotation.

[image: Example Angles]

If you are interested in how I figured it out, I made a table to visualize essentially what I am doing from *0°* - *360°*.

[image: Table]

Comment: Hello @Noah-Wilder, Regarding your equation. What is n stand for and why does it have the value of 0.5 and not something else?

Comment: @hamada147, I just used *n* as a placeholder for the value 0.5. The fact that I extracted 0.5 as a variable, *n*, was just a stylistic choice to help make the equations more concise.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you forgot to set the `startPoint` on your `CAGradientLayer()`. The code below is the code you've provide, plus my addition.

```
import UIKit

class GradientView: UIView {

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        // 1
        self.backgroundColor = ColorPalette.White

        // 2
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds

        // 3
        let color1 = ColorPalette.GrdTop.CGColor as CGColorRef
        let color2 = ColorPalette.GrdBottom.CGColor as CGColorRef
        gradientLayer.colors = [color1, color2]

        //** This code should do the trick... **//
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5)

        // 4
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]

        // 5
        self.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what's making yours not work, but I do have a GradientView that I use that can be horizontal or vertical, and works with the ui builder stuff. Feel free to run with it and refine for your needs:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable  class  GradientView: UIView {
    var gradient:CAGradientLayer
    @IBInspectable var startColor:UIColor = UIColor.whiteColor() {
        didSet {
            self.updateGradient()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var color1:UIColor? = nil {
        didSet {
            self.updateGradient()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var stop1:Double = (1.0 / 3.0) {
        didSet {
            self.updateGradient()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var color2:UIColor? = nil {
        didSet {
            self.updateGradient()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var stop2:Double = (2.0 / 3.0) {
        didSet {
            self.updateGradient()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var endColor:UIColor = UIColor.blackColor() {
        didSet {
            self.updateGradient()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var isHorizontal:Bool {
        get {
            return self.gradient.endPoint.y == self.gradient.startPoint.y
        }
        set {
            self.gradient.endPoint = newValue ? CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0) : CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.configGradient()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.configGradient()
    }

    func configGradient() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.layer.insertSublayer(self.gradient, atIndex: 0)
        self.gradient.masksToBounds = true
        self.gradient.frame = self.bounds
        self.gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        self.gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
        self.updateGradient()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.gradient.frame = self.bounds
    }

    func updateGradient() {
        var colors:[CGColorRef] = []
        var locations:[NSNumber] = []
        colors.append(self.startColor.CGColor)
        locations.append(0.0.nsNumber)

        if let color = self.color1 {
            colors.append(color.CGColor)
            locations.append(self.stop1)}

        if let color = self.color2 {
            colors.append(color.CGColor)
            locations.append(self.stop2)
        }

        colors.append(self.endColor.CGColor)
        locations.append(1.0.nsNumber)

        self.gradient.colors = colors
        self.gradient.locations = locations

        self.layer.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An angled gradient can be achieved using some basic trigonometry. You can achieve it by subclassing UIView, as I describe in my [blog post on the subject](https://appcodelabs.com/create-ibdesignable-gradient-view-swift).

First define some variables:-

```
// The end point of the gradient when drawn in the layer’s coordinate space. Animatable.
var endPoint: CGPoint

// The start point of the gradient when drawn in the layer’s coordinate space. Animatable.
var startPoint: CGPoint

// the gradient angle, in degrees anticlockwise from 0 (east/right)
@IBInspectable var angle: CGFloat = 270
```

The core function, below, gets the start and end points in unit space.

```
// create vector pointing in direction of angle
private func gradientPointsForAngle(_ angle: CGFloat) -> (CGPoint, CGPoint) {
    // get vector start and end points
    let end = pointForAngle(angle)
    let start = oppositePoint(end)
    // convert to gradient space
    let p0 = transformToGradientSpace(start)
    let p1 = transformToGradientSpace(end)
    return (p0, p1)
}
```

This simply takes the angle that the user specified and uses it to create a vector pointing in that direction. The angle specifies the rotation of the vector from 0 degrees, which by convention points east in Core Animation, and increases anti-clockwise (counter-clockwise).

The rest of the relevant code is below, and is concerned with the fact that the resulting point is on the unit circle. The points we need, however, are in a unit square: the vector is extrapolated to the unit square.

```
private func pointForAngle(_ angle: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
    // convert degrees to radians
    let radians = angle * .pi / 180.0
    var x = cos(radians)
    var y = sin(radians)
    // (x,y) is in terms unit circle. Extrapolate to unit square to get full vector length
    if (fabs(x) > fabs(y)) {
        // extrapolate x to unit length
        x = x > 0 ? 1 : -1
        y = x * tan(radians)
    } else {
        // extrapolate y to unit length
        y = y > 0 ? 1 : -1
        x = y / tan(radians)
    }
    return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
}

private func oppositePoint(_ point: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: -point.x, y: -point.y)
}

private func transformToGradientSpace(_ point: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    // input point is in signed unit space: (-1,-1) to (1,1)
    // convert to gradient space: (0,0) to (1,1), with flipped Y axis
    return CGPoint(x: (point.x + 1) * 0.5, y: 1.0 - (point.y + 1) * 0.5)
}
```

And ultimately everything must be called from an update function:-

```
private func updateGradient() {
    if let gradient = self.gradient {
        let (start, end) = gradientPointsForAngle(self.angle)
        gradient.startPoint = start
        gradient.endPoint = end
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
    }
}
```

For the full implementation please see my [blog post](https://appcodelabs.com/create-ibdesignable-gradient-view-swift).

Comment: i tested with angel = 0, the direction color is from left -> right, it's wrong and must be top -> BOttom