# How to add angle in gradient from UI?

Tags: ios, swift, cagradientlayer

I have this code to modify the colors from the interface :

```
@IBDesignable
class GradientView: UIView {
    @IBInspectable var firstColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear{
        didSet{
            updateView()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var secondColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear{
        didSet{
            updateView()
        }
    }

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass{
        get{
            return CAGradientLayer.self
        }
    }

    func updateView(){
        let layer = self.layer as! CAGradientLayer
        layer.colors = [ firstColor.cgColor, secondColor.cgColor ]
        layer.locations = [ 0.5 ]
    }
}
```

How can I add here to modify the angle?

Comment: You can use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53066958/3991157

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angled Gradient Layer In Swift 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038055/angled-gradient-layer-in-swift-2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the properties `endPoint` and `startPoint` of your `CAGradientLayer`. Like so:

```
let x: Double! = angle / 360.0
let a = pow(sinf(Float(2.0 * .pi * ((x + 0.75) / 2.0))),2.0);
let b = pow(sinf(Float(2 * .pi * ((x+0.0)/2))),2);
let c = pow(sinf(Float(2 * .pi * ((x+0.25)/2))),2);
let d = pow(sinf(Float(2 * .pi * ((x+0.5)/2))),2);
```

I hope this helps!