# How to add a gradient background with LaunchScreen.storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I want to add a gradient background to LaunchScreen.storyboard. 
Since this gradient changes with the diagonal of the screen, it is difficult for UIImageView to support screens with different aspect ratios.

So far, Launch Image was used to solve this.
However, Apple enforces the use of LaunchScreen.storyboard.

How do I add this to LaunchScreen.storyboard?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: The launch screen interface is supposed to be static. You can't  modify the launch screen in storybaord dynamiclly, you should implement a custom launch screen to achieve what you need

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angled Gradient Layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038055/angled-gradient-layer)

Comment: @ZGski As Mac3n says, LaunchScreen.storyboard cannot do this because it cannot execute custom code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an image editor (or whatever suits you) to create that as an image.

You can then add a `UIImageView` to your `LaunchScreen.storyboard` (Content Mode: Scale to Fill).

---

**Edit**

LaunchScreen storyboards cannot execute any code - and that includes trying to use a custom subclass.

If scaling a single image doesn't suit your needs, you ***do*** have a (limited) option.

`UIImageView` - including when used in a LaunchScreen - can have different images for different size traits:

[image]

You cannot get down to actual screen sizes, but using different images for the different trait combinations might do the trick.

Comment: Thank you. This is effective for simple gradients, but cannot be used if the orientation of the gradient differs depending on the width and height of the screen. Does UIImageview have the option to have different images for different resolutions? This is an issue with LaunchScreen.storyboard where custom code is not available.

Comment: I have tried this with 2 : 1 aspect ratio image.  This answer seems to work correctly.